# How to force a tableview to display contents fetched from web service immediately?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview

Hi my iPhone app users a web service to update a tableview, first saving the items in core data.

Currently, however, there is a long delay between when I believe the data is present in Core Data and when the tableview refreshes on the screen.

With a blank install of the app, the app screen can stay blank ten to fifteen seconds after the spinner stops before data appears on screen, however, if you tap on one row, you can view the detail for the item suggesting the data is there in core data.  Similar, if you scroll up and down, the screen begins to populate. My question, is how can I get the data to appear on the screen as soon as it is saved to core data?

I've tried placing `[self.tableView reloadData]` all over the place, but it seems to have no effect on the timetable for displaying data.  The only time it has an effect is if I place it in viewDidLoad after the call to the web service.  In this case, placeholder images appear for each row but the text does not appear for the same ten to fifteen seconds.

Here is the viewDidLoad method where the web service call is made.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

           self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        _spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 200);
        _spinner.tag = 1;//todos
        [self.tableView addSubview: _spinner];
        [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:_spinner];
        _spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
        _spinner.hidden = NO;
        [_spinner startAnimating];

        //GO TO BACKGROUND THREAD FOR SERVER CALL
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kServiceURL];
                    [self fetchServiceData:data];//SYNCING NOW TAKING PLACE

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.tableView reloadData];
            [[self.view viewWithTag:1] stopAnimating];
        }); 
        });
    }
```

I also placed self.tableView reloadData in viewWillAppear without success.

Comment: What happens in fetchServiceData?

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a suggestion**

`viewWillAppear` is most likely called long before you receive your data. So adding `reloadData` there wouldn't help.

There is a method for all UIViews named [setNeedsDisplay()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) that tells the system that that view needs to be redrawn. I don't know if reloadData do that automatically or if you need to do it manually. Try adding `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]` after your `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  Did not change things.  It is curious that the images load immediately but not the labels.  Perhaps it has something to do with tableview delegate methods

Comment: Verify your iboutlets are connected, or that your init method is set up correctly. Also double check cellForRow